# call Fancybox in parent from iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I have 2 pages, my index.html and social.html. I cleaned out my index and left only the jquery code need for [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) What I am trying to do is to have images inside social.html and when clicked on it, it would open fancybox and show it but in index.html not inside the iframe. The error that comes up is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'showImage' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
(anonymous function)social.html:103
  onclick
```

this is my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showImage(image) {
            $.fancybox('<img src="img/' + image + '" alt="" border="0" />');
        };
</script>

</head>

<body>
<iframe src="social.html" scrolling="no" border="0" width="579" height="505" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

in IFrame page:

```
 <img src="img/picture1.jpg" alt="" class="thumbs" onclick="parent.showImage('picture1.jpg');"/>
```

PS: both pages are on same domain...
EDIT: video.js -> this is from fancybox I didn't make this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(".video").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'         : 640,
            'height'        : 385,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
            'wmode'             : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });

        return false;
    });



});
```

Comment: thats what I thought so but it doesn't it keeps giving me that error :S

Comment: What is there inside `js/video.js`. If this js has any error than `showImage` function will not be parsed by the browser JS engine. And only in that case it will throw this error.

Comment: i just added video.js code but thats straight from fancybox I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Do you see any JS error on page load in the console?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, you should be using fancybox v2.x to seamlessly do that (patching fancybox v1.3.x doesn't worth the effort)

Second, you need to have in both pages, the parent page and the iframed page, loaded jquery and fancybox css and js files in order to transcend fancybox properly,

so in both pages you should have at least something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.css" />
```

and

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

then in your iframed (child) page your script is basically the same (but with the right fancybox options for v2.x ... [check the documentation here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs))

```
$(".video").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            // more options (v2.x) etc
```

but instead of this

```
        $.fancybox({
```

do this:

```
        parent.$.fancybox({
```

then fancybox will show in the parent page out of the boundaries of the iframed page

**UPDATE**: [Demo page here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_16Jan12.html)

Comment: I tired this, download the latest version of everything. On the single page(iframe) if I just put $('.fancybox').fancybox(); it works but then I put parent.$.('.fancybox').fancybox(); and it says unexpected token, and if I put parent.$('.fancybox').fancybox(); it gives same DOM error :S

Comment: Well, if you are tired then there is nothing we can do (so I wonder why you asked for help)... but if you don't realize the "latest version" of everything is meant to improve the software you are using and fix existing bugs. We are not giving you orders, we are giving you ideas to solve your issue... (y si no quieres, pues no y mucha suerte entonces)

Comment: I'm sorry it was a typo i meant "I tried this" I would never put down or not appreciate the help being given.  I was trying to do several things at the same time and I know you spent your valuable time giving me help and didn't want to leave you hanging without an answer whether it worked or not.  And of course having the latest of anything is better b/c most bugs are removed don't have a prob with that either.  All this just a typo :)

Comment: OK, no problem no harm done. It's funny how a typo can turn something in a completely different way. Please just let me know if the solution worked or not. If it did, please don't forget to check the answer as correct. If not I will post you a live example that you can use as a reference.

Comment: i know but so far I've been trying and havent been able to get it to work, i even tried with the demo that i downloaded from fancybox, if you could put a live demo it would help get over this hump which turned from a hump to a mountain lol

Comment: There you go: http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_16Jan12.html .... don't forget to check the source code of both, the parent page and the iframed page (and don't forget to check this answer as the good one  ;)

Comment: THANK YOU!! you know what I think it was before? I was testing local host and like right now i copied exactly what you had and still wouldn't work, so then I uploaded and it worked!! crazy huh? but thank you so much!

Comment: The **parent.$.fancybox({** doesn't work on the localhost. It worked when i kept the same code on live server.

Comment: with parent.$.fancybox({...}) the parent fancybox is closing.is it possible that both parent and child remain open until done explicitly.

Comment: @Ankit `parent.$.fancybox` refers to the page that contains the `iframe` where the fancybox will be launched from. Otherwise I am not sure what you are asking, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Ive encounter this problem before and was able to find a solution. Here is what iv done.
in my iframe page i called the parent window with the href e.g. 
`onClick="callMe('www.google.com')"` or if pics "/images/pics.png" 
and call this script in my parent page

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function callMe(site){ 
      $(".sample").fancybox({ 
         'width' : '97%', 
         'height' : '97%', 
         'href' : ''+site+'' //force href to change its site from the call function in the iframe page 
      }); 
      readyFancy() call to trigger the decoy link page 
 } 

 function readyFancy(){ 
      $("a.sample").trigger("click"); 
 } 
 </script>
```

in my parent html we right a decoy link (this one is from the example on load fancybox)

```
<body> 
<a href="#" class="sample"></a> 
</body>
```

You can download a working example here..
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1TI7BdxGAbvYzBiZjNiMDYtNjY4ZS00NDczLWE2YjQtODNlMjU4YTNjYWI0/edit?authkey=CP_H9rAC

Comment: It's worth to mention that your solution is for fancybox v1.3.4 and it is helpful for people who doesn't want to upgrade. With my proposed solution using v2.x, the advantage is that you don't need to modify the original fancybox files and that your script will still work with future upgrades of fancybox.

Comment: @JFK...thanks JFK i did not realize that you already include it in your upgrade. Anyways thank you so much for giving us fancybox.

Comment: I didn't develop Fancybox ... Janis is the man http://stackoverflow.com/users/486595/janis

Comment: Why even bother with a decoy link? If you've looked at the examples provided by Fancybox, like you said. See my answer how.

Comment: @esims this was a solution way back 10 years ago. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Since the img is on an iframe is a different webpage. So Jquery is on index.html but the img doesnt, thats why JQuery cant get to the image.

Maybe using something like this... But i dont think it would work

On index.html script part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //function to active fancybox on the thumbs class inside the iframe
    //Not sure it works on iframes, probably it doesnt.
    $("#iframeID.thumbs").fancybox();
});
```

And add the id to the iframe declaration
    < iframe src=\"social.html\" id="iframeID" etc... rest of properties>

But, my advice is to use divs instead of iframes.
You also should remove the onclick from the image for non-obstrusive Javascript.

Check the tutorial: http://fancybox.net/howto 
If you want a similar tutorial in spanish you can check my site too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upgrade from  fancybox v1.3.x and you also don't need fancybox in your iframe page.

**Iframe:**

```
<a href="#" class="fancylink" data-url="www.example.com">Some link</a>

$('.fancylink').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    parent.show_fancybox(url);
});
```

**Parent:**

```
function show_fancybox(url) {
    $.fancybox({
        'type'          : 'iframe',     
        'width'         : 640,
        'height'        : 480,
        'href'          : url       
    });
}
```