# Return to iFrame instead of parent on closing Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have an iFrame that's rendered inside Fancybox. Within the iFrame I have another link that calls Fancybox on the parent page as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1213627). All is working as desired. On closing Fancybox that was called from within iFrame using Fancybox on the parent page, I return to the parent page. However, I would like the behavior modified to return to iFrame instead of the parent page.

The Fancybox that I currently have in iFrame:

```
jQuery('.container').on('click', 'a.fancybox-large', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    parent.jQuery.fancybox({
        href            : this.href,
        padding         : 0,
        closeBtn        : true,
        fitToView       : true,
        helpers         : { overlay: {opacity: 1, css: {'background-color': '#000000'}} }
    });
});
```

Any suggestion?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

You can select what element inside of the `iframe` you want to focus on using the `.focus()` method.

So having an input field inside the `iframe` for instance

```
<input type="text" class="field" />
```

EDITED: add full script.

add to your script the `afterClose` option

```
jQuery('.container').on('click', 'a.fancybox-large', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 parent.jQuery.fancybox({
  href            : this.href,
  padding         : 0,
  closeBtn        : true,
  fitToView       : true,
  helpers         : { 
   overlay: {
    opacity: 1, 
    css: {'background-color': '#000000'}
   } 
  },
  afterClose: function(){
   jQuery('.input').focus();
  }
 });
}); // on
```

and your focus will be on that `input` field inside the `iframe` after fancybox is closed

Comment: Thx for the reply. I tried your suggestion. However it throws an error "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope".

Comment: weird, I tested it and works just fine. Can you share a link to see what type of error and if this is related to the new option? ... also check that you options are separated by comma but the last. Just in case, `afterClose` is fancybox's API option so it should be included inside your fancybox custom script.

Comment: Well, I have a local install, so no means of sharing a link. The error crops on the new option and the line where code breaks is jQuery('.input').focus();. I have another instance of Fancybox that also uses afterClose. There I have no problem with afterClose. I have the commas correct. Just to confirm, I am adding the afterClose function to my code that I mentioned in the question. I guess that's what I am supposed to do. Correct? Secondly, the code that I have in the question is part of the js file that loads both on the parent page and the iframe page.

Comment: Update: I replaced jQuery('.input').focus(); with an alert. Same issue.

Comment: do you have somewhere inside the iframe `<input class="input" ...`?

Comment: Yep! I do have the input element inside of the iframe.

Comment: The code in my edited answer works just fine. See demo http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_08mar12.html

Comment: Thx for a working demo. The only difference I see in your demo and my current code is that I have the iframe loaded inside of Fancybox. In other words, I have a link on parent page that loads the iframe in Fancybox. Then I have another link, this time within iframe that's already loaded inside of Fancybox. This other link opens an image in new Fancybox wrapper. I checked in Firebug and find that the iframed Fancybox actually closed when the second link to the image was clicked and probably the reason why this solution is not working.