# Fancybox from iframe to parent

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

I'm using the fancybox plugin and I'm trying to send it to the parent window. I have it working on one page, but when I bring it to another page where it's part of a slideshow, I receive an error that it "is not a function". From my understanding, all I needed to do was implement the plugin on the parent page. If anyone can help me find out why this is raising this error I'd really appreciate it!

Page 1

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.localdtvdealer.com/page.aspx?QS=5c591a8916642e737e93c01412d56d5ae266a22b4f55b9f9a54ed7191c748091" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/zipCodeWindowCSS.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.localdtvdealer.com/page.aspx?QS=5c591a8916642e73c41f320542ef4912ec966ef60dc239352e9e3ff3a33d77cf"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/DTVLBjqueryfancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/DTVLBjqueryfancybox2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var corpID = "44444";

$(document).ready(function() {
      if($("#contentPane").length && getCookie("Offer"))
        {
            SetIFrameSource("contentPane","http://www.localdtvdealer.com/BMI/Carousel/iframe/?cid=" + corpID);
            $("#lblLocation").text(getCookie("Location"));
        }

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="" width="720" height="446" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" id="contentPane"></iframe>
</body>
```

Page 2

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe60157077600275741d/m/1/ZipCodeWindowLogoExplosion.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/DTVLBjqueryfancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/DTVLBjqueryfancybox2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function reqParam( name )
        {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
            if( results == null )
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }

   $(document).ready(function() {
      if($("#contentPane").length && getCookie("Offer"))
        {
            SetIFrameSource("contentPane","http://www.localdtvdealer.com/" + getCookie("Offer").toUpperCase() + "LogoExplosion");
            $("#lblLocation").text(getCookie("Location"));
        }
        setSrcDynamically();
    });


  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>

</head>

<body>
<iframe name="base" id="base" class="iframe" src="" overflow="auto;" width="712px" height="397px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
        function setSrcDynamically()
            {
                var pvalue=reqParam('p');
                var i = document.getElementById('base');
                i.src="http://www.localdtvdealer.com/justintest3/#"+pvalue;

            }
        //-->
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987

Comment: I've tried this but it still raises an error. I'm placing the objects in the HTML then to the Javascript then back to the HTML. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I believe I know what the issue is. I have a page with an iframe, and the iframe is pulling in other iframes for each slide. So it is going to the parent, but the parent is within an iframe. Is there a way to target the parent of a parent?

Comment: Fixed!

Basically I was targeting the wrong parent. I was targeting an iframe as the parent. Fixed it by adding another ".parent" object for the frame. ---

     window.parent.parent.$.fancybox ---

instead of ---

     window.parent.$.fancybox ----

Woot!

Comment: Can you post that comment as an answer? That way it's clear you solved your problem (plus we can vote your answer up).

Comment: Sorry, I had to wait a certain amount of time to post this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

Basically I was targeting the wrong parent. I was targeting an iframe as the parent. Fixed it by adding another ".parent" object for the frame.

```
 window.parent.parent.$.fancybox
```

instead of

```
 window.parent.$.fancybox
```

Woot!