# open iframe fancybox from within an iframe so that it opens in the parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox, parent

I can get this to work which opens a fancybox IMAGE from within an iframe

```
<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'myurl'});">Open something</a>
```

Problem I have is that I need to open a fancybox IFRAME. Example code or any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [call Fancybox in parent from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, set type `iframe`:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'myurl', type: 'iframe'});">Open something in iframe</a>
```

But you should do it only when you need to have different options, because you can open other page withing iframe like:

```
<a href="myurl">Open something in iframe</a>
```