# issue opening thickbox from inside an existing iframe

Tags: iframe, parent, target, thickbox

So I seem to have found myself in a bit of pickle. In order to keep a header flash element from reloading every time someone goes to a different page, I encapsulated all my site's content in an iframe. Unfortunately, some of the iframe's include thickbox, which opens an iframe of it's own. The iframe that thickbox opens, requires it be opened on the topmost page, so that the fixed attribute allows the iframe to remain static in the viewport. Because we're already nested into an iframe, this isn't possible.

This is the most promising lead I have so far:
http://blog.codepyro.com/2010/01/thickbox-inside-of-thickbox-iframe.html

Unfortunately, that only replaces the iframe that the thickbox is being opened from, with the content of the thickbox.

I also just came across this, but I'm not sure how I would go about retooling it to suit my needs:
[open iframe fancybox from within an iframe so that it opens in the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406642/open-iframe-fancybox-from-within-an-iframe-so-that-it-opens-in-the-parent)

Here is a link to what I'm working on:
http://www.lalalandmusicfestival.com/site/

The problem area is on the Talent page.

I think if there was a way to force the link to target the "top" or "parent" page with javascript, it may be possible, but I haven't found anything that's been of any use to me yet.

Thanks in advance for your help!