# What do I need to replace in FancyBox File to make it appear in parent?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox

In my javascript I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var no_of_galleries = $('.gallery').length;
    for ( var i = 1 ; i < no_of_galleries ; i++ ) {
         $("a[rel=photo_open" + i + "]").fancybox();
    }
});
```

I tried everything But I can't make it open in  parent. I'm calling this file with iframe, and I want to open images in parent not in the iframe.

If ther eis a solution please tell me, if not tell me what do I need to change in the fancybox file so it will open in parent.

Comment: and you need to open it on parent.$.fancybox({

Comment: I can't just put parent.$.fancybox... it doesn't work

Comment: you have to follow some manual for that... or you can do that using jquery method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved It!

Change the following:

line 351 from 'height' : $(document).height() to 'height' : $(window.parent.document).height()

line 1039 from $('body').append( to window.parent.$('body').append(

lines 674 to 677 from

```
$(window).width() - (currentOpts.margin *2),
$(window).height() - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
$(document).scrollLeft() + currentOpts.margin,
$(document).scrollTop() + currentOpts.margin
```

to

```
$(window.parent.window).width() - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
$(window.parent.window).height() - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
$(window.parent.document).scrollLeft() + currentOpts.margin,
$(window.parent.document).scrollTop() + currentOpts.margin
```

IT really works!! I've tested it

Comment: Without hacking the original js files (fancybox v2.x) http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987

Comment: sorry but for my case that doesn't work! I'm not calling fancybox on click, but on document load. I've tried that method before posting believe me. It doesn't work for my case

Comment: It doesn't really matter, you can always trigger fancybox `onload` form within the iframe ... if I spare some time, I will show you how (if you want)