# open fancybox over another fancybox ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, fancybox

I have a Fancybox which shows me some dialog and a button to click.
When i click this button i want to open another fancybox over the existing one.. or on another position on the screen, but i dont want to lose the already existing fancybox.
I want to fill both of them by an ajax request..
Is this possible?
Because what i tried resulted in losing the original fancybox..

I got this code:

```
$.fancybox.showActivity();
                $.ajax({
                    type        : "POST",
                    cache       : false,
                    url     : "../testservlet?select=1,
                    data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
                    height      : 600,
                    width       : 800,
                    padding     : 30,
                    showCloseButton : true,
                    success     : function(data) {
                        $.fancybox(data);
                    }
                });

$.fancybox.showActivity();
                $.ajax({
                    type        : "POST",
                    cache       : false,
                    url     : "test?select=2,
                    data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
                    padding     : 30,
                    showCloseButton : true,
                    success     : function(data) {
                        $.fancybox(data);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot have more than a single fancybox at the same time ... it has been designed like that.

You could have another fancybox inside of the existing one though (when open an external page -via iframe- with fancybox in it) ...or you could open that inner fancybox on the parent page, creating the illusion that you have two fancyboxes on the same page. [Check here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987)

On the other hand, the only lightbox I remember that supports multiple boxes is [jQuery Tools Overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/multiple.html)

Comment: thank you..
but i dont see on your link how it is possible to create this illusion, when i create it on the parent page?

Comment: create a page that opens a fancybox  (and set `parent.parent.$.fancybox` instead ... see example in link). then open that page from another page in fancybox ... and open the second fancybox inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Open first fancybox in iframe. Then inside that another fancybox can be open.