# Call jquery fancybox from another fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to call another fancybox from an opened fancybox WITHOUT the opened fancybox closing?

see it yourself:
http://jsfiddle.net/unsDG/5/

:D

Comment: Please check this url http://lpld.natives.it/ and click any of the links in the bottom. Do you expect like this

Comment: I don't think is possible. I already answered a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/11231402/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [open fancybox over another fancybox ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224042/open-fancybox-over-another-fancybox-ajax)

Comment: I did search before posting but didn't saw that thread though. I don't know if there exist jquery tools before. Cool thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the parent page, setup fancybox using an iFrame:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".fancybox").fancybox(

{

    width:'75%',

    height:'75%',

    'type' : 'iframe'

});

});
```

Inside the child page, put in your content, ensure it has a valid doctype, import the javascript and css that Fancybox needs again, and then declare your new Fancybox link. It may helps you