# trying to find alternatives because of impossibility to open second fancybox without closing first

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

Im using fancybox to show some content.

But I also have inside my fancybox content, some links to open others fancyboxs that will show pdf´s.

And it is working fine, but When I close my last fancybx opened, I also close my first fancybox opened.

And I was trying to open a fancybox from another without closing the first, but it seems impossible do this.

Because When I close the last opened fancybox, When I go back to the first fancybox opened, this fancybox is closed.

Do you know some plugin similar to fancybox, to use just on my pdfs links? And so I can show my articles content with fancybox, and open my pds inside my fancybox with a "similar fancybox plugin" without closing my fancybox...?

Or a plugin like fancybox that allows me to do what I want without using two different jQuery plugins.

Because I already tried with shadowbox and jquery overlay and its not working correctly.

You can see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/420/,

If you try to open my second fancybox, when you close second fancybox you see
that first fancybox opened is closed.

I have this html:

```
<article class="loop-news">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <span>Dahttp://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/5EV8r/#updatete of today</span>
  <p>content of my article</p>
  <a class="fancybox" href="#show">Read more</a>
  <div class="fancybox-container">
    <div id="show">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <span>Date of today</span>
      <p>content of my news</p>
      <!--here I have some pdfs inside fancybox, that will open other fancybox-->
      <div  class="pdfs">
        <li><a class="fancybox_pdf" href="pdf1.pdf">Title of pdf</a></li>
        <li><a class="fancybox_pdf" href="pdf1.pdf">Title of pdf</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

When I click in my "Read more" link I will open my fancybox with my content, using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({   
        maxWidth    : 800,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '100%',
        height      : '100%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',     
    });
```

And inside my fancybox with my content I have also some links to open pdfs inside fancybox, using this script:

```
$(".fancybox_pdf").fancybox({
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        autoSize: false,
        type: 'iframe',
        iframe: {
            preload: false
        } 
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11231402/1055987

Comment: Thanks for your answer JFK. But I dont really see how your link can help me. I already try to jquery tools overlay as I said in my question, but I dont have the effect I want.