# Open lightbox fullscreen when clicked in iFrame?

Tags: iframe, fancybox, lightbox

Here's my page: http://ilijaveselica.com/Gallery/GetCroatiaFavPhotos

I'd like to implement this page into another website. I tried with iframe but lightbox (fancybox) opens only within iframe, not whole page. Any idea how can I solve this without much pain?

Here's how it looks: http://www.croatia-photography.com/

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine of doing that is including the gallery elements within the fancybox script itself.

So, in your page http://ilijaveselica.com/Gallery/GetCroatiaFavPhotos, instead of having this :

```
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
 // API options here
});
```

...and all your hidden html anchors for each image of the gallery, have something like this :

```
$('.gallery').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 parent.$.fancybox([
  {href:'images/01.jpg', title: '01'},
  {href:'images/02.jpg', title: '02'},
  {href:'images/03.jpg', title: '03'}
 ],{ 
  // API options here
 }); // fancybox
}); // click
```

Notice that we are providing the `href` and `title` within the brackets. Also notice that we used `parent.$.fancybox` to indicate that fancybox will open in the parent page and outside the iframe.

Then the only html you would need to open the gallery outside the `iframe` is :

```
<a class="gallery" href="javascript:;"><img src="{thumbnail}" alt="" /></a>
```

For further reference and DEMO (see update), check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987

Comment: I tried it and uploaded online but it's not working at all on iframe now.

Comment: This works only inside the same domain. It doesn't work cross-domain

Comment: you should always consider the Same Origin Policy when working with iframes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy