# target="_parent" in Fancybox is loading a new window

Tags: fancybox, parent, target

Ok here's a messy one.

I've got an iframe on a page, and in that iframe I've loaded up a Fancybox iframe with a link in it that has target="_parent". My only problem is it's loading the link in a new window for some bizzare reason, not out of the fancybox and into the iframe.

My link is `<a href="http://www.dpdesignz.co.nz/homefresh/lib/checkout.php?checkout=checkout&redirect=order" class="button" target="_parent">Continue Checkout</a>`

You can view an example of the code at https://www.dpdesignz.net/homefresh/dps/success.html. My biggest thing though is that even though this page is on my https://www.dpdesignz.net domain, the link in the button cannot be changed from the http://www.dpdesignz.co.nz to https://www.dpdesignz.net

Can anyone see what may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your link has the `class="button"` but there isn't in any part of your code anything that binds that selector to fancybox

something like:

```
$(".button").fancybox({
 width : 650,
 height: 400,
 type  : "iframe"
});
```

otherwise it will always open in anew window

Comment: thanks but this is the page already in the iFrame. I'm trying to get this one to open outside of the iFrame in the parent iFrame, but instead it's opening a new window

Comment: then follow the code and examples from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987