# Fancybox 2 - Image stretching in iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox in an iframe. When I try to open an image with fancybox, fancybox gives wrong sizes -it gives window width not image width- and image inside fancybox is stretching this size.

For example: Image dimensions: 2592x3872. Fancybox stretches to 853x395.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm didn't tryed this, just thinking: can you run jQuery in your iframe? If you can, use the `$(window).resize(function() { ... });` to set up your new image size...

Answer (score 0):

could you clarify what do you mean with **fancybox in an iframe**?

... does it mean that you are using `type: "iframe"` in your API options?

... or does that mean that you are firing fancybox from within an iframe inside your page? (or both?).

Anyway, try adding `autoSize: false` and `fitToView: false` to your API options like:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    autoSize: false,
    fitToView: false
});
```

Comment: I'm running fancybox within an iframe inside a page. When I set "fitToView" to false, images seem their original size. It didn't solve my problem.

I think the problem is there is no doctype in the iframe.

Comment: @SevilYILMAZ : so check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 if that helps

Comment: It was my mistake. I've changed `current.aspectRatio` value to `false` for images in source of fancybox for different development. I forgot it. Now I add a control for this. This topic can be closed. Thanks for your help.