# Fancybox Image Gallery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have the next code in iframe and i achieve it gets display in the parent but now i dont know how i can agroup the images like image gallery in fancybox example.

i saw this in an example:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.imagen').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
parent.$.fancybox([
{href:'images/01.jpg', title: '01'},
{href:'images/02.jpg', title: '02'},
{href:'images/03.jpg', title: '03'}
],{
// href: this.href,
helpers: {
overlay: {...............
```

but i do not want that because links are going to be dynamic. I would like use something like
 `$(".fancybox") .attr('rel', 'gallery')` and use it like

```
 <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=0" >
```

to achieve see all img with next button as image gallery but i dont what i have to modify.

my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fancybox').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            parent.$.fancybox({
                href: this.href,
                helpers: {
                    title: { type: 'inside' },
                    overlay: {
                        opacity: 0.3
                    } // overlay
                    //, buttons: {}
                } // helpers
            }); // fancybox
        }); // click
    }); 
</script>
```

body

```
<a class="fancybox" href="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=14" >
  <img alt="" src="../Resources/background.png" width="100" height="100"/>
</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=6">
<img alt="" src="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=6" width="100" height="100"/>
 </a>
 <a class="fancybox" href="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=20">
    <img alt="" src="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=6" width="100" height="100"/>
 </a>
```

I am using fancybox 2.1.3 Please HELP ME!!!!
Thanks in advance

```
I have to do this?
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fancybox').click(function (e) {
    like i said before at start???
    });//click
    $('.fancybox').attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
         JFK code??
     });
    });//
```

Comment: Have you looked into the Fancy box documentation for help?

Comment: yesh I saw this <a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'myurl'});">Open something</a> but it doesnt work with ashx

Answer (score 0):

If you have these links :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=14" >
  <img alt="" src="../Resources/background.png" width="100" height="100"/>
</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=6">
  <img alt="" class="fancybox" src="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=6.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=20">
  <img alt="" src="Lector.ashx?ImagenId=6.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
</a>
```

... notice that none of them have an image extension so fancybox doesn't know what `type` of content to handle ... you need to tell it using the `type : "image"` API option. Check [Fancybox documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support) **FAQ** tab, No. 5

Your full code should look like :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.fancybox').attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
            type : "image", // force type of content to image
            helpers: {
                title: { type: 'inside' },
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.3
                } // overlay
            } // helpers
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**EDIT** : I noticed that you are also setting the class `fancybox` in your `img` tags (second link in your code above) like :

```
<img alt="" class="fancybox" ....
```

... that could have unexpected results so better remove it from there. Only the `<a>` tags should have the class `fancybox`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. <img alt="" class ="fancybox" was a mistake.. JFK i see u have alot of exp with jquery and i would like ask you how i can display this in iframe parent i tried before ur code and it only is displayed in the iframe and i want display it in the parent. with the same attributes  $('fancybox').attr('rel','gallety')... i tried  parent.$('.fancybox').attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({... but it do not work. Btw i am beginner sorry for noob questions im reading ur link thanks in advance

Comment: Btw i have to do type : "image", and .attr('rel','gallery') in the .click function?

Comment: @user1887471 : to open fancybox in parent from iframe check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 for detailed isntructions.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fancybox').attr('rel', 'gallery').parent.$.fancybox({
                type: "image", // force type of content to image
                helpers: {
                    title: { type: 'inside' },
                    overlay: {
                        opacity: 0.3
                    } // overlay
                } // helpers
            }); // fancybox
        }); // ready  why this doesnt work?

Comment: Do i have to include the click event in $(document).ready ? or just your code? because if i include my click part and your code i got 2 fancyboxs, 1 in parent another in the iframe if you see in my click code i achieve display it in parent but i actually dont know how to display them as a slide gallery i mean with .attr('rel','gallery') thank you for reply. i added parent.$.fancybox({ type:.... but doest not work :S