# Fancybox 2 load another content from fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, joomla, resize, fancybox

I'm using fancybox 2 (on joomla 3)

I'm trying to the following effect:

I have a catalogue page with items which open in a fancybox iframe using `data-fancybox-type="iframe" rel="cars"` 
the new item loaded has the doctype and head elements with full jquery and fancybox linked.
the iframe is small,300x650px and is composed of few thumbnails and text. 
I am trying to achieve some method, to - upon clicking one of the thumbnails - launch the full image (800x800px):
a) instead of the opened iframe (close if and open the full image with gouping, close the image and the iframe comes back)
b) load the image inside but stretch the parent iframe, after closing the image stretch it back to original size.
any of these work, the idea is to open a small image gallery triggered from rather small iframe (if it'd be bigger then the images load inside without problems)

I use this code for the parent:
(I have tried with width, height: 70% or any other value)

```
$(".iframe_launch").fancybox({

    fitToView   : false,
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    closeEffect : 'none',
    openEffect      : 'elastic',
    padding     : 0,
    scrolling   : 'visible',
    scrollOutside   : 'no'

});
```

and this for the loaded content:

```
$(".thumbs").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 900,
    maxHeight   : 805,
    fitToView   : false,
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    openEffect      : 'elastic',
    padding     : 0,
    scrolling   : 'visible',
    scrollOutside   : 'no'
});
```

I have triend targetting the

```
parent.$(".thumbs").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 900,
        maxHeight   : 805,
(...)
```

and some other solutions from stackoverflow but can't get it to work with satisfactory results.
btw. It doesn't have to be fancybox, but the `'elastic'` opening is just perfect

Comment: does this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 help?

Comment: Yes, I get the TypeError: parent.$.fancybox is not a function, trying with window.parent too