# Fancybox iframe gallery in parent page

Tags: fancybox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [call Fancybox in parent from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe)

Hi I have `iframe` on my home page. Inside it is a gallery and I want to open pictures in my parent page when I click on the `fancybox` picture. I tried anything but it opens only one picture and no full gallery with next and previous buttons.

My example:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <title>FancyBox 1.3.4 | Demonstration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function readyFancy(){
            $("a#sample").trigger("click");
        }
        function callMe(site){ 
            $("#sample").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'href'              : ''+site+'',
                'autoScale'          : true,
                'onStart'           : function(){$("body").css({'overflow':'hidden'});},
                'onClosed'          : function(){$("body").css({"overflow":"visible"});}
            });
        readyFancy();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body style="padding: 20px;">
<a href="#" id="sample"></a> <!-- here we set a decoy link for the frame to be triggered-->
<p>Below is an iframe</p>
<iframe src="sample.html" width="300" height="200"> <!--the link of the iframe-->
</body>
</html>
```

`sample.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body >
<div>
<a onClick="parent.callMe('http://localhost/fan/1_b.jpg');" href="#" ><img src="1_s.jpg"></a>
<a onClick="parent.callMe('http://localhost/fan/2_b.jpg');" href="#" ><img src="2_s.jpg"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are over complicating things. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 make sure you check DEMO and source code for both, parent and iframed page (gallery).

Comment: Do you have a link for download, because I tried it according to the instructions but it doesnt work

Comment: sorry, not link to download (the idea is to provide help, not to do other people's work ;), the demo should be enough ... compare the code

Comment: BTW, calls to `parent` may not work in `localhost`, you may need to test them in a server environment

Comment: I dont understand, i am doing everything according to the instructions but when I click on image gallery it doesnt work. Nothing will happen

Comment: create a demo page with the issue and share a link then

Comment: Ohh i had a bad target, and how do I do that I did not write pictures like this href:'01.jpg', title: '01'. I export images from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ID` as selector `$("#selector").fancybox();` then switch to classes - `$(".selector").fancybox();`

Comment: Yes but this doesnt solve my problem

Comment: it should. did you update your jquery?

Comment: You dont understand what I want