# Fancybox iframe edit

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I use this script https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 on my website, but I want edit this and I dont know how. I want to script get images from database i dont want to write any like this, it is possible? The normal fancybox just add rel="group", but there doesnt work it. Have you any solutions please?

```
[
{href:'images/01.jpg', title: '01'},
{href:'images/02.jpg', title: '02'},
{href:'images/03.jpg', title: '03'}
]
```

Comment: Do you need to periodically replace images? If then you can use `ajax` to request for images from the server and update the images

Comment: There is a simpler solution?

Comment: If you need to change image periodically, then you must implement `ajax` like one which is a simpler solution.

Comment: And have you any example? because I'm not in AJAX

Comment: `There is a simpler solution?` = hire a developer ;)

Comment: @user1993243, you can start here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Ok I did it in AJAX but I have a problem when i click on second picture it always open first picture. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already call your set of images via ajax so it returned for instance

```
{href:'images/01.jpg', title: '01'},
{href:'images/02.jpg', title: '02'},
{href:'images/03.jpg', title: '03'}
```

... and supposing that you have a series of thumbnails, each one corresponding to each image in the ajax call like

```
<div class="thumbs">
    <img src="images/01_thumb.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/02_thumb.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/03_thumb.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

... **notice** that I wrapped the thumbnails in a `div` with `class="thumbs"` ...then you would need to catch what thumb was clicked (the `index`) and open the fancybox starting with the corresponding image so you can do

```
$('.thumbs img').click(function () {
    var startWith = $(".thumbs img").index(this)
    $.fancybox(myAjaxCall, {
        type: "image",
        index: startWith
    }); // fancybox
}); // click
```

... **notice** that I got what thumb was clicked using the `index()` method in

```
var startWith = $(".thumbs img").index(this);
```

... and used the API option `index` to tell fancybox with what image to launch the gallery.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HRs64/)**