# Fancybox iframe popup when site is loaded via another domain using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a member-site that is operational.

That sites uses fancybox iframe "pop-up" and all works well. Now I want to allow webmasters to connect to member area via iframe and everything works well, but I am just curious if I can make fancybox popup overlay to go all over the browser instead of just "iframe" on user-domain....

To make it more clear my site resides on www.MyScriptDomain.com and there, when fancybox popup is triggered - overlay covers entire browser viewport.

Now if on www.SomeOtherDomain.com my member site is called via iframe like this:

```
<iframe name="inlineframe" src="http://MyScriptDomain.com/index.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="980" height="500"></iframe>
```

when fancybox popup is triggered overlay pop out, but it covers only area of 980px / 500px, so is there a way to make nice integration, so it will actually cover entire browser viewport ?

Comment: Search for "lightbox "from iframe"" You'll find many working options.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way. You need script-access to the document where the iframe is embedded to accomplish this, but you don't get any access when both documents reside at different domains.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 if that helps, however you may have cross-domain issues as already pointed out.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of issues as within the iframe I have fancybox iframe which is actually calling some PHP scripts with complicated call-backs that needed to be passed, so I eventually gave up on trying this. I did have some success with messaging stuff, but it's way too complicated to be implemented to get it to work as I imagined + some of stuff didn't work in IE9.... :)