# fancybox loads way down the bottom of my iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Using Fancybox with it's new api, trying to build a site that works on iPhones & real computers...  So, in my CSS, I had to define my page size, instead of just having the website's content as 80% iframe.  All of a sudden that broke how FancyBox works, and now it's window opens out of frame down the page somewhere.  So, do I fix the website so it doesn't load content in iFrames? Or do I tweak Fancybox?  Happy to pass on more details...

FancyBox api says something about this, but I can't find where it is set.

"iframe  Options for content type "`iframe`"
Object; Default value:"

```
{
scrolling : 'auto',
preload   : true
}
```

first time poster... long time reader here.

Comment: Working content inside iframes is not always user friendly ... personally I try to avoid them unless there is no other option (some special scripts, etc.) ... what you could try is open fancybox outside the iframe on parent page so it aligns with the last. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 if that helps

Comment: great solution.... I will attempt to implement today, thanks for the prompt response!  Sounds like the perfect fix.