# Picture viewer that can be called from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe

I'm trying to find a solution for this problem for quite a while now and I think I'm going to flip out :)

So is there a `jquery` solution for a picture viewer that can be implemented in a facebook app that runs in an `iframe`.

The problem is (that i can see) that all of them are appending functions on the body element but `Facebook` is preventing that from happening.

Comment: The old problem regarding cross domain scripting? If so, give up. There's no solution for this.

Comment: I'm building a app for Facebook and i know that there is a solution because i'v seen other apps that have that function so despair or not I'm still searching:)

Comment: I've done 2 "apps" for FB before. Quoted because they just "iframe" a website provided and call it app. LOL
Anyway... So I see that you have a different problem and I'm not so sure I got it.

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe

Comment: Thanks :) i think that will help, ill post the success if any .