# Center a lightbox in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm trying to use the fancybox jQuery plugin in a Facebook iframe canvas app but when the lightbox opens its centered to the iframe width and height but not to my viewport. Is there any way I can fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The contents of the iframe is not allowed to know anything about its parent window, for security. See this for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting