# call Fancybox in parent from Iframe with no manual open

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox-2

i guess i could get the answer here -> [call Fancybox in parent from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe/8855410#8855410) and the demo page shows really what i would like (http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_16Jan12.html) but the problem is that i do not have the same script...

Instead of (i guess this is the manual opening) :

```
$(".video").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        // more options (v2.x) etc
```

I call the pictures like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    // etc
```

I tried to change my code like this (based on the answer & demo) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    parent.$(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    // etc
```

...but it does not work. Is somebody can tell me how should i change my code that the thumbs who are in the iframe, open the images on the parent page, resized to the screen ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you `console.log( parent.$ );` does it log that it exists or that it's undefined?

Comment: Dave, sorry, i am not an expert of javascript, can you show me how to integrate it in the whole code pls ?

Comment: @Dave Stein

If you thought about :

    `$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log(parent.$);
 $(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
     padding: 0,`

...it loads the pictures but does not work, it loads in a normal way without considering the parent page screen.

Comment: You need to download firebug. Google that. Open the console. The `console.log` would show you if `parent.$` exists. I was not suggesting to console.log and then still do `$('#.fancybox-thumbs')`

Comment: Ok, thanks Dave... i was laughing, so much i do not know about javascript... i have Firebug but i did not know what means consol.log.

Comment: @Dave Stein  thanks for your suggestion but as i wrote in an answer here below, i have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, unfortunately never (!) from my own question on the forums... i share it with you, maybe it helps for someone :

1 First i had the .css and .js files linked to both parent html and iframe html.

2 My parent html

```
<body>
<div id="more">
<div class="container">
        <div id="sensuality-div">
            <iframe id="sensuality-frame" src="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/sensuality.html" width="100%" height="100%" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts" ></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

3 My iframe html

```
<body id="sensuality-body">

    <div class="view view-add"> 
        <img src="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/uploads/thumbs/41.jpg" alt="Thierry Mercier 16" /> 
        <div class="mask">
            <a href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/uploads/images/41.jpg" class="fancybox-thumbs" rel="group1" alt="Model : Thierry Mercier - 2009 June" title="34 Dance in the Dark"> 
                <h4>Dance in the Dark</h4> 
            <p>Model : Thierry Mercier</p> 
            <info>Click for zoom</info>
            </a> 
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="view view-add"> 
        <img src="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/uploads/thumbs/41.jpg" alt="Thierry Mercier 16" /> 
        <div class="mask">
            <a href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/uploads/images/41.jpg" class="fancybox-thumbs" rel="group1" alt="Model : Thierry Mercier - 2009 June" title="34 Dance in the Dark"> 
                <h4>Dance in the Dark</h4> 
            <p>Model : Thierry Mercier</p> 
            <info>Click for zoom</info>
            </a> 
        </div> 
    </div>

</body>
```

4 My original code for calling fancybox (not manual opening) is in the followings (i have it on both parent and iframe pages):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
    padding: 0,

    openEffect : 'elastic',
    openSpeed  : 150,

    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    closeSpeed  : 150,

    closeClick : true,

    prevEffect : 'elastic',
    nextEffect : 'elastic',

    closeBtn  : true,
    arrows    : true,
    nextClick : true,

    beforeShow: function () {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
        this.title = '<h3>' + this.title + '</h3>' + $(this.element).attr('alt') + '<br />';
    },

            afterShow: function() {
    },

            helpers : {
        title : { type: 'inside' }
    }
    });
    });
</script>
```

5 THE HACK : I combined the code i found (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-56981.html) with mine and i ADDED AN ADDITIONAL SCRIPT to my iframe page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    if(top !== window){
        var $$ = parent.jQuery;
        $$('#sensuality-div').html($('#sensuality-body').html()).find('a').fancybox({
            padding: 0,

        openEffect : 'elastic',
        openSpeed  : 150,

        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        closeSpeed  : 150,

        closeClick : true,

        prevEffect : 'elastic',
        nextEffect : 'elastic',

        closeBtn  : true,
        arrows    : true,
        nextClick : true,

        beforeShow: function () {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
            this.title = '<h3>' + this.title + '</h3>' + $(this.element).attr('alt') + '<br />';
        },

        afterShow: function() {
        },

        helpers : {
            title : { type: 'inside' }
        }
        });
        $("#sensuality-body a").click(function(e){
            $$('#' + this.class).click();
        });
    } 
    else {
        $("#sensuality-body a").fancybox({
        padding: 0,

        openEffect : 'elastic',
        openSpeed  : 150,

        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        closeSpeed  : 150,

        closeClick : true,

        prevEffect : 'elastic',
        nextEffect : 'elastic',

        closeBtn  : true,
        arrows    : true,
        nextClick : true,

        beforeShow: function () {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
            this.title = '<h3>' + this.title + '</h3>' + $(this.element).attr('alt') + '<br />';
        },

        afterShow: function() {
        },

        helpers : {
            title : { type: 'inside' }
        }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Maybe you can make it much easier, maybe i added a lot of unnecessary codes, what i know is that it works fine...

I saw that many people look for a solution for that kind of question, hope to help you !

Soon you will be able to see it on [www.igorlaszlo.com](http://www.igorlaszlo.com)

Comment: You will be able to see it soon on www.igorlaszlo.com