# Position Fancybox 2 to the Top of Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox 2. I would like it positioned to the top of the *viewport*.

I tried the following code:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   topRatio:0
});
```

This positions fancybox to the top of the page, not the viewport. This works if a person isn't scrolling down the page, however, when a person starts to scroll down the page fancybox is out of the screen.

Screenshot of Fancybox when scrolled:

[image: Screenshot]

I have Fancybox in an iframe and wonder if that may be part of the problem?

How do I get Fancybox to always stay within the viewport?

**UPDATE**

In attempting to get this to work it would be best if it opens outside of the iFrame. I attempted the following code:

```
$( ".fancybox" ).click(function(e){
    parent.$.fancybox({
    href: this.href
});
    return false;
});
```

and

```
$( ".fancybox" ).click(function(){
    parent.$.fancybox();
    return false;
});
```

In both cases it doesn't work and there are no errors.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 ?

Comment: @JFK - That may work but how do I get it work work with the code in my question?

Comment: @JFK - See my update please. I cannot get this to work.

Comment: you need in both pages (the parent page and the iframed page) jquery and fancybox css and js files in order to transcend fancybox properly.

Comment: @JFK - It still doesn't work. There is no longer an error, it just doesn't work. Is there another way to do it than the code in my question?

Comment: have you compared your code with the demo http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_16Jan12.html?