# Open Gallery called from an Iframe with fancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

Well, i have follow the instructions on that question: [call Fancybox in parent from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe)

But, isn't work for me.

On the example, he has a gallery inside the javascript like:

```
$('.imagen').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    parent.$.fancybox([
        {href:'images/01.jpg', title: '01'},
        {href:'images/02.jpg', title: '02'},
        {href:'images/03.jpg', title: '03'}
    ],{
    //          href: this.href,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                opacity: 0.3
                } // overlay
                //, buttons: {}
            } // helpers
        }); // fancybox
    });
```

On my case, i'm using like the fancyBox page instructs:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'myurl'});" rel="group1">Open something</a>
<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'myurl'});" rel="group1">Open something</a>
<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'myurl'});" rel="group1">Open something</a>
<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'myurl'});" rel="group1">Open something</a>
```

It's working, but is showing simple images, not as gallery

how i can turn this on gallery?

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: lol, i know, but on there, isn't an option or example with iframe and gallery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your iframe :**

HTML :

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="1.jpg">Image#1</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="2.jpg">Image#2</a>
```

JS :

```
$(document).on('click','.fancybox',function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    var images = [];
    $('[rel="'+rel+'"]').each(function(){
        var image = $(this).attr('href');
        images.push({href:image});
    });
    parent.$.fancybox(images);
    return false;
});
```

Don't forget to **include jQuery** file in your **iframe**.

*Untested , pls test with your real images*

Parent : Need jQuery.js, Fancybox.js

iFrame : Need jQuery.js and my script upper

Comment: i think you don't understand the question. I want to open gallery from inside an iframe, not open iframe inside fancyBox

Comment: i have tried this: 
`<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href: 'myurl', rel:'group1'});">Open something</a>`, but din't work too

Comment: i need to put this code on  iframed (child) page right? and i need to put the fancyBox script on both pages (iframe and iframed)?