# How to force fancybox to display in index.html and not in the iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I've been searching for ages on how to do this and no matter how many answers and demonstrations I find it just won't work for me.

I have a bunch of thumbnail images in an iframe, and when I click on those fancybox only appears inside the iframe.  I'm trying to force fancybox to come outside the iframe to show the larger images instead of inside the iframe but every attempt results in the image being blown up to full size inside the iframe.

I have the source and css in both the iframe and index.html, I'm using fancybox version 2.1.5, this is what I have in both headers...:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

... and this is what I have in the iframe:

```
    $('.fancybox').ready(function() {
        parent.$.fancybox();
        $("a[href$='.jpg']").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();
    });
```

Even now it's ignoring the parent. part and continues to show fancybox inside the iframe.  If I change .ready to .click then the whole image blows up to full size inside the iframe.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 make sure to check the source code of the demo

Comment: possible duplicate of [call Fancybox in parent from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe)

Comment: I tried that example a few days ago and it wasn't working initially, but out of curiosity I removed the base tag from the header and it started to work. However because I've had to add the gallery to the script it means no matter which thumb image I click on it'll always start with the first image in the script. Is there a way to make it display the image that I selected instead of the first one?