# Append Fancybox from iframe to parent using window.postMessage

Tags: jquery, fancybox, postmessage

I have a Fancybox modal that lives in an iframe that needs to open full width in the parent window. I know this can be done but accessing the window.top.jQuery and appending Fancybox that way. Though due to Same Origin security policy accessing the window.parent.jQuery isn't possible. I'm passing required app config information to the parent by using window.postMessage. Could there be a possible solution using post message to do this?

Thanks

Comment: this might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [call Fancybox in parent from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe)