# fancybox.open is undefined but loading from console I can open it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

My fancybox integration struggles continue....but I am making progress. My page loads and I see no errors in the debug console. When I click my button that should open fancybox I get...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined.
```

I had this error yesterday but then I couldn't access fancybox from the console either.

I improved how my scripts are injected into the header and...I still get the error on my click event.

**BUT**

now I can load fancybox from the console and it works great. So I'm figuring I'm just not referencing something correctly for my click event to see it.

In my click handler I do this...

```
$.fancybox.open((....});
and I get the undefined error.
```

at the console I do the same thing...

```
$.fancybox.open((....});
```

and it works??

So I thought I'd check and see if my click handler could even see the fancybox object. I added this to my event handler.

```
var fncy = $.fancybox;
```

set a breakpoint and it is undefined. So I am at a loss as to why my event handler can't see fancy box but the console can....

Just to clarify again the event handler is NOT firing until the user clicks a button so it seems to me that the fancy box scripts etc. have all loaded no??

Very grateful for any light that can be shed.

JB

---

@Dave Yes I have doc ready call as...

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   $('.fncy').fancybox();
});
```

This is my html element...

```
<div><span class="fncy"></span></div>
```

When I query this element in the console I get...

```
$('.fncy')
[]
```

when I query an object in the demo page...

```
$('.various')
[
 <a class=​"various fancybox.ajax".....>a bunch of elements
]
```

Is  a bad choice to bind fancybox to?

Comment: did you tried calling fancy box inside document.ready function ?

Comment: @Dave See edit for greater detail.

Comment: I am not getting ideas as to what may be wrong with code portion you added in question.. If you are able to replicate this problem in jsfiddle then Pls add one jsfiddle otherwise need access to entire code and jquery version to find out problem... Better add a fiddle with same version of jquery and fancybox that you are using..possibilities of solving this will increase..

Comment: If this is your actual script `$.fancybox.open((....});` then it has a syntax error (double open parenthesis instead of opening `{` bracket)

Comment: @JFK Sorry that is not it. That's just me and my fat fingers.

Comment: here an example how to use `$.fancybox.open()` : http://jsfiddle.net/eJEma/ ... check what you might be doing wrong

Comment: Just started a new thread with a more generic theme. This will help describe my environment better...@Dave suggested creating a fiddle which is a great idea but I can't figure out how to recreate iframe effects in jsfiddle.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412996/why-does-my-function-not-see-an-object-but-from-the-debug-console-it-is-there

Comment: You are over complicating things. It seems that the main issue is that you want to trigger fancybox from within an iframe (where I guess fancybox is not loaded but in the main page). If I am correct, then check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987

Comment: I just figured it out...and yes you are correct in what I want to do. My dirty test I just added all the fancybox libraries to the iframe...which still makes no sense to me as I can't get over the fact that I have switched back to a function executing on the parent so why is the iframe context hanging around. For a more elegant solution I am going to use the dummy link mentioned in the so post you included....if you'll write a quick answer I definitely mark it for you as it would have been the answer had I not dumb lucked into mere second before.

Comment: Upvoting **[my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987)** would be good enough.