# Fancybox image in iframe - open in parent Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I have a problem using the fancybox plugin with an iframe. My current setup is:

Load news articles in a bootstrap modal, which contains an iframe from another domain (from the news system) - so for example: i am on page.domain.com and load content from news.domain.com, where every news article is provided. So everything works great, but i have problem when ill try to open a fancybox gallery.

When i use the fancybox like this:

```
$('a.lightbox').fancybox({
openEffect: "none",
closeEffect: "none",
titleShow: 'true',
titlePosition: 'inside',
helpers:  {
    title : {
        type: 'inside'  
    },
    thumbs : {
        width: 90,
        height: 60
    }
},
beforeLoad: function() {
this.title = $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt');
}
});
```

The fancybox opens on every item with class lightbox, and everything looks fine. But in the iframe, it get opened inside the iframe. But i want to open the gallery outside, in the parent window.

So normally i use:

```
parent.$.fancybox({
```

But now, i am loosing the **'a.lightbox'** selector. So i would need to manually push the items like this:

```
 beforeLoad: function () {

// here i need to read out all images in the same group, and push it modally

            this.group.push(
                { href: "... image1", type: "image", title: "Picture 01", isDom: true },
                { href: "... image2", type: "image", title: "Picture 02", isDom: true }
            ); 
        }
```

But i dont think that is a good option for me.

Is there an better way how to open a fancybox in the parent window, using the standard **$('a.lightbox')**.... selector?

Comment: I guess you have read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 .... I am not sure you can open fancybox in the parent page with the regular bind-selector format `$(".selector").fancybox()` (unless someone can prove me wrong)

Comment: Hello. Yes i have read this - but when i use this $(".selector").fancybox() - then the fancybox gets always opened in the iframe. The only way for me is to use parent.$.fancybox (like in your link) - but then i need to push manually every data to my fancybox (like Images for gallery) - i think the problem is that i am not able to get dom elements inside my iframe.