# Clicking outside of fancybox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fancybox-2

So I am trying to be able to use everything outside of my fancybox without closing it.

So I have closeclick set to false.
I made it draggable too so I can move it around the screen but if I try to click on a button it wont let me.
I researched everywhere but everyone only has ways to close it by clicking out not fire an event outside of it.
I know it is run through an Iframe so researched that too but no luck still.

If this is not possible is there another way of having popups. I want to be able to click things outside of the fanxybox.

-edit after a month.

Been researching and have yet to figure it out. Was working on other projects then this one came up again.
Now I'm also trying to figure out how to open a fancybox within a fancybox. Make the 2nd one draggable (not the first one) and be able to click inside of the fancybox. Unless fancybox is not the way to go with all of this is there any other way of doing it.

Here is my first page

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                fitToView: false,
                beforeShow: function () {
                    this.width = 1000;
                    this.height = 300;
                }  
            });


     <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="">
<center>
<img src="images/calendar.png" border="0" style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" /></center>
                                                </a>
```

Here is what it is inside of the fancybox on another page.

```
 parent.$(".fancybox").fancybox({
                fitToView: false,
                beforeShow: function () {
                    this.width = 500;
                    this.height = 100;
                },
                afterShow: function () {
                $(".fancybox-wrap").draggable();
            }
            });
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="">
<img src="images/arrow-right-3.png" border="0" style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" /></a>
```

But when I run that one the fancybox does not come out it just goes to the next page. Not sure if it's closing the first one to open this one or if it just redirects.

I tried [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe/8855410#8855410) but that didn't seem to work.
This is something that has bugged me for ages so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have your code online somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the helpers.overlay option to false which will prevent the overlay from showing:

```
parent.$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    beforeShow: function () {
        this.width = 500;
        this.height = 100;
        // If helpers.overlay = false doesn't work, uncomment below.
        // $('#fancybox-overlay').remove();
    },
    helpers: {
        overlay: false
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        $(".fancybox-wrap").draggable();
    }
});
```

Failing that, within the `beforeShow` method, you can simply remove the overlay element. There is an area around the dialog that is unclickable (for the gradient effect) but everything else worked for me.

HTH

Comment: You are awesome! So I can click outside which I have been wanting. So when I try to add parent. to it, it doesn't work. If I take it off it works but it stays inside of the fancybox. Is there anyway of getting it out of the fancybox or should I just make the first one bigger and then the one inside the size I want. Want to try to keep it all small so be awesome if I can get the fancybox outside of it. (I am using the fancy-overlay.remove)

Comment: @KratosMafia - Just to clarify, are you trying to initiate a new fancybox from an iframe already shown within fancybox?

Comment: Okay. I want a fancybox to open which I am. Then within that fancybox open a second one and be able to move that one around but make the first fancybox clickable. If that makes any sense. But I want the second fancybox to also be outside of the first.

Comment: I don't think FancyBox would be the best solution to be fair, as it's only intended to have one open at a time. You're probably better off using jQuery UI's Dialog - https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: If I can figure out how to move the fancybox around atleast while inside fancybox I can dela with that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I got it. I had "FanycBox" instead of "Fancybox" inside my Fancybox so the jquery wasen't readying it right. Thank you for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1) Set the `overlayShow` option to false

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                fitToView: false,
                overlayShow: false,
                beforeShow: function () {
                    this.width = 1000;
                    this.height = 300;
                },
                afterShow: function () {
                    $(".fancybox-wrap").draggable();
                }
            });
```

2) Set the padding to 0, you can achieve that by adding `padding: 0` to your fancybox container or adding it to your CSS file

```
.fancybox-wrap {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```