# The fancy box image in the iframe open in parent Window?

Tags: fancybox

However, when I load up the page with the iframe and click on the image link in the page that is in the iframe I want the lightbox to display in the parent window and not in the iframe.

Comment: Question not clear.... Need some code, to see and help...

Comment: Please read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use window.parent.functionName()

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855410/1055987 if that helps (although is for fancybox v2.x)

Answer (score 0):

you can call parent function with below code

```
<a onclick="parent.ShowLighbox('http://example/sampleImagePath.jpg');" href="#" >Show Lightbox</a>
```

and on your parent windows implement that function  like below

```
function ShowLighbox(imageURL){
//write your code to show lightbox
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete examples ?

Comment: that is a code snippet, I have shown you how you can call parent function and send an image URL, try to implement it and let me know if something wrong.