# Open fancybox 3 into iframe parent

Tags: iframe, fancybox, fancybox-3

Here is my problem :
- i have an fancybox 3 gallery intro an iframe
- when i click to one of the link, i would like the image showing on top of the parent of my iframe

I have made many researches and tried several solutions

I found this : [call Fancybox in parent from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853727/call-fancybox-in-parent-from-iframe/8855410#8855410)
but it only provide a solution for fancybox 2

Here is my code on the iframe :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    parent.$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        href:  this.href
    });
});
```

Please note

- i have included jquery and fancybox 3 both in the iframe and the parent
- fancybox works like a charm independently in the iframe and the parent, but cannot be called from the iframe to be displayed in the parent (my problem)
- i have also tried :

  $(".fancybox", top.document).fancybox

  $(".fancybox", window.opener.document).fancybox

  $(".fancybox", window.parent.document).fancybox

None of these worked

Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I hope you red the docs while doing "many researches". From the docs:

> To access and control fancybox in parent window from inside an
>   iframe:
>
> ```
> // Adjust iframe height according to the contents
> parent.jQuery.fancybox.getInstance().update();
> ```

This should give you a clue that you can use `parent.jQuery.fancybox` to use API from the parent page.

Then, API section should give you a clue how to open image gallery programmatically:

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        src  : '1_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'First caption',
            thumb   : '1_s.jpg'
        }
    },
    {
        src  : '2_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'Second caption',
            thumb   : '2_s.jpg'
        }
    }
], {
    loop : false
});
```

So, combining these two snippets should give you the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for my late reply. I guess i didn't read well the documentation, i didn't make the link between those two elements which answer perfectly to my question. Thank you for your attention Janis.