# Fancybox 3 - display iframe gallery full screen

Tags: iframe, fancybox, fancybox-3

I know this question has already been asked but mostly for Fancybox 2 (and not 3) and the only answer I did found didn't help me though.
My web page has two frames, one hosts the Fancybox Gallery. So far, when I click on images, they only open in the corresponding frame and Id like the images to fill the whole screen. Following the answer here ([Open fancybox 3 into iframe parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580013/open-fancybox-3-into-iframe-parent/55151992#55151992)) I made the following code but I didn't went right.
Did I forgot something ? Should I put some code in the main page of my project, the one that holds the two iframes ? Something else I should do ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<link  href="jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.getInstance().update();
});

$.fancybox.open([
    {
        src  : 'IMG_3301.JPG',
        opts : {
            caption : 'First caption',
            thumb   : 'IMG_3301 - copie.JPG'
        }
    },
    {
        src  : 'IMG_3302.JPG',
        opts : {
            caption : 'Second caption',
            thumb   : 'IMG_3302 - copie.JPG'
        }
    }
], {
    loop : false
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="IMG_3301.JPG">
    <img src="IMG_3301 - copie.JPG">
</a>

<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="IMG_3302.JPG">
    <img src="IMG_3302 - copie.JPG">
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `parent.jQuery.fancybox` you can access fancybox within the parent iframe, and, to start fancybox in parent iframe, simply combine your two snippets, like `parent.jQuery.fancybox.open(..)`

Example:

```
  var $links = $(".imglist a");

  $links.click(function () {
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.open($links, {
      // Your custom options
    }, $links.index(this));

    return false;
  });
```

Demo - http://fancyapps.com/tmp/embed/

Comment: Thanks Janis. You're right about blindly copying but I'm really not a JS specialist as you can see. Can you be more precise about your suggestion and tell me how put this in place ? Thanks

Comment: I added the sample code. btw, why would you want to use iframes to display images?

Comment: Thanks Janis. Actually, I'm building an interactive map and when a marker on the map is clicked, a html page with marker's information is loaded in another iframe of the layout. This page contains images displayed with Fancybox. But so far, when clicked to enlarge, the images only display inside the iframe hosting the html page https://www.laurentgontier.com/IrishBorder/IrishBorder.html