# Open Fancybox3 from an iFrame in parent page

Tags: iframe, parent, fancybox-3

I'm sorry but I don't understand Janis's answer on this page 
[Open fancybox 3 into iframe parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580013/open-fancybox-3-into-iframe-parent/49585775#49585775) , this is too technical for me as it doesn't give a precise answer.

I can't work out what should be the script needed to open in a parent page from that answer that is pointing to the documentation (which is found  in a section about opening iframes, instead of opening FROM an iframe into a parent page) and unfortunately I can't comment on that page so here I am.

> How to access and control fancybox in parent window from inside an iframe:

```
// Close current fancybox instance
parent.jQuery.fancybox.getInstance().close();

// Adjust iframe height according to the contents
parent.jQuery.fancybox.getInstance().update();
```

OK so that closes or updates the parent window, but how to open various links in the parent window ?

Then Janis says:

> This should give you a clue that you can use parent.jQuery.fancybox to use API from the parent page.

But how to "phrase" it ? in a script ?

> Then, API section should give you a clue how to open image gallery programmatically:

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        src  : '1_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'First caption',
            thumb   : '1_s.jpg'
        }
    },
    {
        src  : '2_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'Second caption',
            thumb   : '2_s.jpg'
        }
    }
], {
    loop : false
});
```

Does that mean you have to make a list of all the images you want to open in the parent page in one script ?
If so that doesn't make sense when you have many images and defeats the purpose of making each link call fancybox individually like so :

```
<a href="images1.jpg" data-fancybox data-caption="image 1">
<img src="images/image1_sm.jpg"  alt="" class="image"/></a>
```

Or does it mean you have to make a script for each picture you want to be opened in the parent page ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that would open image gallery in current page or in parent page:

```
var $fb_links = $('[data-fancybox="images"]');

$fb_links.click(function() {

    if ( window.self !== window.top ) {

        window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.open( $fb_links, {
            //animationEffect : 'fade',
            hash : false
        }, $fb_links.index( this ) );

    } else {
        $.fancybox.open( $fb_links, {}, $fb_links.index( this ) );
    }

    return false;

});
```

I hope you can see that it is not so scary to create your own click event that starts the script.

Comment: Thanks Janis but sorry that doesn't help at all. 
"In current page or parent page" but how do you choose ? I need parent page.
And as I mentionned I don't have a gallery, I have various one-image spread through the i frame. That probably seems obvious to you, I don't know what I should put instead of fb_links (nor what that corresponds to), the data-fancybox="images" is "images" a class ?

Comment: Sorry, I just do not know how to properly respond to questions like this.

Comment: yes I can see that :) I'll revert to version 2 and the simple way to ask each link to open fancybox in a parent page.

Comment: Look, if you would just simply given an example of your page with all your "various one-image spread through the i frame", I am sure I would given an appropriate answer in no time. There is nothing complex here, it is just like Lego where you put pieces together to archive desired results.